# Correctly remove exchange server

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, format

We have an intranet domain where an Exchange 2013 was installed for testing purposes. This is no more used and can be deactivated. Now I need to format the server where Exchange was installed. I'd like to know if there are preliminary actions to perform... do I need to uninstall exchange? What about active directory?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot undo the prep of the domain.
However you need to remove Exchange properly, so any future installations do not cause a problem.

Mail disable everything you can, so user, groups and contacts. Note that is DISABLE - delete will remove the AD object as well.
You can then remove Exchange using add/remove programs.

If there is anything left, then the installer will stop and tell you - just clear through everything it asks for until the uninstall goes through.